# Why is jsconfig.json file reporting a 'not found' problem?

Tags: visual-studio-code

My jsconfig.json file is reporting a problem:

```
File 'c:/.../node_modules/source-map/source-map' not found.
  The file is in the program because:
    Root file specified for compilation
```

It always reports it twice, and points to the first `{` in the file.

Here's my `jsconfig.json`

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es6",
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "@/*": ["src/*"],
        }
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

When I reload VSCode, it's gone for a few minutes and then reappears while using VSCode.

Comment: I have been having this problem persistently across multiple projects, with different node_modules packages being flagged as needed and still have yet to find a workable solution...

Answer (score 2):

This was fixed for us by installing a later version of source-map as a dev dependency.

```
npm install source-map --save-dev
```

At the time of writing this, the package.json entry under devDependencies is:

```
"source-map": "^0.7.3"
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding `"noEmit": true` to `compilerOptions` **and** reloading VSCode seems to work for me.